# "Invalid type specified." exception when signing using CMS with a certificate in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, rsa, x509, pkcs#7

I'm trying to sign a CMS message with a certificate knowing its data (byte[]) and the associated key, or with a dummy certificate.
The code is working in .NET Framework but fails in .NET Core 3.1

```
public static byte[] Sign(string providerName, string containerName, byte[] certData)
{
    try
    {
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"), new byte[] { 1, 2, 14 });
        var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters
        {
            ProviderName = providerName,//Utimaco CryptoServer CSP
            ProviderType = 1,
            KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey,
            KeyContainerName = containerName
        });


        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certData);
        certificate = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaKey);
        var signer = new CmsSigner(certificate)
        {
            DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26")
        };

        signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

        var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
        var signedData = signedCms.Encode();
        return signedData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing:

I load the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` from the same CSP container used to sign the certificate (`certData`) to get a certificate with the private key.

The code above throws an exception of type `WindowsCryptographicException`, at the `ComputeSignature` call:

> Invalid type specified.

Stack trace:

> at
> Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.HelpersWindows.GetProvParameters(SafeProvOrNCryptKeyHandle
> handle)    at
> Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.PkcsPalWindows.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2
> certificate, Boolean silent, Boolean preferNCrypt)    at
> Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.PkcsPalWindows.GetPrivateKeyForSigning[T](X509Certificate2
> certificate, Boolean silent)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSignature.RSAPkcs1CmsSignature.Sign(ReadOnlySpan`1 dataHash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithmName, X509Certificate2 certificate, AsymmetricAlgorithm key, Boolean silent, Oid& signatureAlgorithm, Byte[]& signatureValue)    at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSignature.Sign(ReadOnlySpan`1
> dataHash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithmName, X509Certificate2
> certificate, AsymmetricAlgorithm key, Boolean silent, Oid& oid,
> ReadOnlyMemory`1& signatureValue)    at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner.Sign(ReadOnlyMemory`1
> data, String contentTypeOid, Boolean silent,
> X509Certificate2Collection& chainCerts)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner
> signer, Boolean silent)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner
> signer)    at Program.Sign(String providerName, String containerName,
> Byte[] certData) in
> D:\me\Projects\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\Program.cs:line 239

Also, doesn't work using a dummy certificate:

```
    CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest(
        "CN=CMS Signer Dummy Certificate",
        rsa,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

   using (X509Certificate2 cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(now, now.AddYears(1)))
   {
       CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
       ...
   }
```

To make sure the key doesn't have a problem, I signed with it (`rsaKey.SignData(...)`) and it works.

The only case where it works when I used a certificate from a file, I have on my machine:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\MyCert.pfx", "123456");
```

Comment: It seems like you are using [SHA-1](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.14.3.2.26) to sign data, maybe the algorithm is deprecated?

Comment: I tried SHA512/256 also, same exception

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: We switched to .NET framework, didn't investigate a lot into it

Answer (score 0):

You hardcode provider type to 1:

```
ProviderType = 1,
```

which is not always the case and you just ran into this case. You should pass actual provider type. I suspect that your key is stored in Key Storage Provider (rather than legacy CSP) and it is not accessible from `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class. This is another possibility for exception.

This code block makes 0 sense to me:

```
var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters
    {
        ProviderName = providerName,
        ProviderType = 1,
        KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey,
        KeyContainerName = containerName
    });


    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certData);
    certificate = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaKey);
```

What you are trying accomplish here is hard to undertstand for me. Actually, you don't need this code block. Pass certificate with `HasPrivateKey = true` directly to method and use it, i.e.:

```
public static byte[] Sign(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    try
    {
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"), new byte[] { 1, 2, 14 });
      
        var signer = new CmsSigner(certificate)
        {
            DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26")
        };

        signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

        var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
        var signedData = signedCms.Encode();
        return signedData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the type is not always the case 1"? do you mean it may have different values (.NET FX& Core)? I just made sure it's "1" in .NET Core.
To make sure that the key is not the problem, I signed with it (`rsa.SignData(..)`) and it worked, 
Also about the code block, sorry for not illustrating: I assigned the certificate its private key from the same CSP Parameters used to sign it when created the certificate, so that `RSACryptoServiceProvider` key is the certificate's associated key.

Comment: yes, there are lots of provider types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.providertype?view=netcore-3.1.

Comment: I'm using the provider "Utimaco CryptoServer CSP" which has the type 1

Comment: My point was that you must not hardcode provider type in your code to make it more universal. Did you try updated code snippet? I believe, it should work since I eliminated `RSACryptoServiceProvider` reference which is not compatible with CNG.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your solution? it doesn't seem to be different from my code (the Dummy certificate one) the `req` you use is signed with `rsaKey`

Comment: I mean last code snippet is suggested code. It doesn't have `rsaKey`.

Comment: I've updated my response by including complete solution.

Comment: How do you create the `certificate` passed to the `Sign` method?

Comment: it depends on where your certificate is stored. Either, from Windows Certificate Store or from PFX.

Comment: The certificate creation is the main problem (as I illustrated in the question), did you try the code at your side, in .NET Core project?